# android: .nomedia file was created somehow. how can that be?

Tags: android

Since last week images from my app do not show up in my gallery anymore. Now I just found the reason for that. Somehow there was a .nomedia file created, so this directory is not scanned. 
This is awkward! I never created that file. 
Anyone has some idea how such a thing might happen?

Comment: Maybe some other app on the phone created this file because it didn't know what the directory was?

Comment: @AleksG: The folder is located at "/sdcard/myAppName"- why would another app create a .nomedia file in some random folder. The file is only present in my own apps folder- so I would have guessed that it was created by my own app somehow.